# Cron job not executing if I set it to trigger few minutes from now

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I am attempting to test my `cron` job by setting it a few minutes (let's say 10) from the current time. For instance, if right now is 5:00 PM, I set:

```
10 17 * * * dotnet <full path to .net core dll>
```

When the clock strikes 5:10 PM, the job is not executed.

On the other hand, if I set the `cron` job to execute every minute:

```
* * * * * dotnet <full path to .net core dll>
```

It is successfully executed every minute.

[I've looked up reasons for why a bash command doesn't execute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work). Unfortunately none of the suggestions explain why one works and the other one does not.

OS: Ubuntu AWS Instance
Note: the `date` command gives me the correct time I am using as a reference.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this issue in an Ubuntu aws instance I have access to, but cron just works. `28 15 * * * ubuntu touch /home/ubuntu/test.txt` worked with no problems. Do you get cron-mail alerts in `dotnet` user mail spool?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your timezone?  Cron runs using local system time, so if, for instance, your system is running on UTC time but you have a TZ environment variable that's adjusting your user time, your crontab will still be executing in UTC time.

Suggested test:

Set it to execute at

10 * * * *

so it will execute in a few minutes *regardless of the hour*.  If it works, then the most likely issue is a timezone offset making the hour you specified not the hour you meant to specify :)